# Is there a suitable table design to store SQL queries?

Tags: sql, database

For example,
I want to save the query condition

```
where a=1 or b=2

or

where a=1 and b=2 and c=4
```

by structuring the columns of the table rather than the raw sql text. Do you have a good table design?

Comment: Databases already have mechanisms for storing queries - views, stored procedures, functions of some kind or another. Why are you trying to invent another mechanism rather than using those supported by your database system?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Conceptually, the view table is correct as you said. However, I want to store and manage conditions in a physical table rather than a view table. The reason is that conditions are frequently changed and we want to manage them intuitively.

Comment: In addition, there is a requirement to change the values corresponding to specific conditions to pre-defined standard values. It can be viewed as mapping information for changing raw data to standard structure.